# For Loops to Create Shapes in p5.js

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I'm new to coding and working in P5.js. I'd like to create 3 arrows, spaced a couple of pixels from one another (the space/distance between them doesn't really matter to me, I'd just like to generate 3 arrows).

I'm trying to do this by practicing for loops, variables, and functions, but might be over-complicating this for myself because nothing is working. I created the arrow using beginShape() and set the vertices, and then set it as a function. I'd then like to set the function to be a variable, and have a for loop output 3 arrows.

Am I CRAZY here/have no idea what I'm doing/is my logic regarding how for loops, etc. work wrong? I need a tutor, haha. Any help is appreciated! Here is my code (the commented out bit at the top are instructions for my class' homework assignment) When I run it now a single arrow appears.:

```
// Assignment: Study and use beginShape() and endShape() to draw 3 separate sketches. Each sketch must contain vertices //
// ( vertex() ). tools you will need: beginShape(), endShape(), vertex(), for loop //

var functionArrow = Arrow();
function setup() {
createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight); 
}


function draw() {
  background(255);
  Arrow()
  for (var i=Arrow; i < 500; i+=5); { //loop through to display the triangles//
  }

  function Arrow() {
  beginShape();
  vertex(180,82);
  vertex(207,36);
  vertex(214,63);
  vertex(407,11);
  vertex(412,30);
  vertex(219,82);
  vertex(223,109);
  endShape(CLOSE);

}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you need to do a few things to get this working the way you described.

Right now your `arrow()` function always draws the arrow in the same location. So the first thing you need to do is **parameterize** your `arrow()` function so that it draws an arrow based on a location you give it. Here's a little example that draws three circles:

```
function drawCircles(x, y){
   ellipse(x, y - 25, 10, 10);
   ellipse(x, y, 10, 10);
   ellipse(x, y + 25, 10, 10);
}
```

Then you can call that function using different values:

```
function draw(){
   drawCircles(100, 100);
   drawCircles(200, 100);
   drawCircles(300, 100);
}
```

You could also put it in a for loop, and use the loop variable to decide the parameters:

```
function draw(){
   for (var i = 100; i <= 300; i += 100) {
      drawCircles(i, 100);
   }
}
```

Note that this is just an example, but this should at least get you started with some correct syntax. Also note that I've defined my `drawCircles()` function at the same level as the `draw()` function. You have your `arrow()` function inside your `draw()` function, which probably isn't what you want to do.